# Derivative of $\mathrm{diag}\left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}\right)\boldsymbol{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-system

The task is to compute the derivative
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial\mathrm{diag}\left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}\right)\boldsymbol{x}}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} \;\;\text{with} \;\; \mathrm{diag}\left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}\right)=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}\right)_1 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
0 & \left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}\right)_2 & 0 & \dots \\
0 & 0 & \left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}\right)_3 & \\
\vdots & \vdots & &\ddots
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
To this end, we can use $\mathrm{diag}\left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}\right)\boldsymbol{x}=\left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}\right) \circ \boldsymbol{x}$,
where $\circ$ denotes the component-wise product/Hadamard product. Deriving the $i$-th row of this expression with respect to the $p$-th component of $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ results in
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{ij}x_j+b_i\right)x_i}{\partial x_p}&=
\frac{\partial \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{ij}x_j+b_i\right)}{\partial x_p}x_i+
\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{ij}x_j+b_i\right)\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_p}
\\
&=
A_{ip} x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n A_{pj} x_j + b_p.
\end{align}
Hence, when $\boldsymbol{a}_p^\top$ is the $p$-th row of $\boldsymbol{A}$, the full the derivative is
$$
\frac{\partial \left(\mathrm{diag}\left(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{b}\right)\boldsymbol{x}\right)}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}=\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11}x_1+\boldsymbol{a}_1^\top\boldsymbol{x}+b_1 & A_{12} x_1+\boldsymbol{a}_2^\top \boldsymbol{x}+b_2 & \dots \\
A_{21}x_2+\boldsymbol{a}_1^\top\boldsymbol{x}+b_1 & A_{22} x_2+ \boldsymbol{a}_2^\top \boldsymbol{x}+b_2 & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Is this correct?

======== **Correction** ========= \

Comparing with the answers, the first part $A_{ip}x_i$ corresponds to $\mathrm{diag}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)\boldsymbol{A}$. However, the second term
$$
\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{ij}x_j+b_i\right)\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_p}
$$
only makes a contribution if $i=p$, i.e, on the diagonal. Using $A_{ij}\delta_{ip}=A_{pj}$ and $b_i\delta_{ip}=b_p$ got rid of the $i$ and led to the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix calculus approach using differentials (I would suggest to consider such approaches rather than elementwise which are prone to error in my humble opinion)

--8< ----------------------------------

Let $y = \operatorname{Diag}\left(A x + b \right) x$, where $\operatorname{Diag}$ creates a diagonal matrix.

Using differentials,
\begin{align}
dy 
&=  \operatorname{Diag}\left(A dx \right) x + \operatorname{Diag}\left(A x + b \right) dx \\
&= \operatorname{Diag}\left(x\right) A dx  + \operatorname{Diag}\left(A x + b \right) dx
\end{align}

The gradient is
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \operatorname{Diag}\left(x\right) A + \operatorname{Diag}\left(A x + b \right). $$

Now, you can cross check with your answer.

--- ADDENDUM ---

Let $a$ and $b$ be the vectors of the same dimension. Then it is straightforward to show that
$$\operatorname{Diag}\left( a \right) b = a \odot b = b \odot a = \operatorname{Diag}\left( b \right) a .$$

Comment: Your answer is correct. I checked it with some code. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: +1  Replacing the `Diag()` operator with a Hadamard product might make it easier to understand the rearrangement which occurs in the second line of the differential.

Answer (score 1):

Using substitutions $u=Ax+b$ and $v=x$ we have

$$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}\begin{aligned}
\frac{ \diag(Ax+b)x}{x}
   &= \frac{ \diag(u)v}{ (u,v)} ∘ \frac{ (u,v)}{ x}
\\ &= \Bigg[\begin{pmatrix} ∆u\\ ∆v\end{pmatrix}
⟼ \diag(∆u)v + \diag(u) {∆v}  \Bigg] ∘
\Bigg[{∆x}⟼\begin{pmatrix} A{∆x} \\ {∆x}\end{pmatrix}\Bigg]
\\ &= \Bigg[{∆x}⟼\diag(A{∆x})x + \diag(Ax+b) {∆x}\Bigg]
\end{aligned}$$

Which is the derivative in functional form. To get it in matrix/tensorial form we need to express it as ${∆x}⟼T⋅{∆x}$, which we can do by noting that

$$\diag(A{∆x})x = (A{∆x})⊙x = x⊙(A{∆x}) = \diag(x)A{∆x} $$

Hence the derivative is

$$\begin{aligned} \frac{ \diag(Ax+b)x}{x} 
&= \Big[{∆x}⟼ \big(\diag(x)A + \diag(Ax+b)\big) {∆x}\Big] 
\\ &\cong \diag(x)A + \diag(Ax+b)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks! The result is correct/works with my code. Although, I'm not entirely sure what happens in the first half. May have a look at derivatives in functional form.

Comment: @opag Derivates are by definition linear functions, and the chain rule tells us that the derivative of a composition is the composition of the derivatives. You may know from linear algebra that any linear function $f：ℝ^n → ℝ^m$ can be represented as a matrix vector product $x↦A_f⋅x$. Recall that matrix multiplication is equivalent to the composition of linear functions. Issues arise when you want to take derivatives w.r.t. higher order tensors (e.g. derivative of matrix w.r.t. a matrix is a rank-4 tensor), and the functional form is often easier to work with in this case.